# WinForms grid that honors linefeeds in data displayed in a cell

Tags: .net

We're sending query results to a grid. Different columns, with different datatypes, on each query.  Is there a grid control that will

a) autopopulate the columns based on the dataset that is set to be its datasource

AND

b) correctly render the linefeeds or carriage returns that appear in a text string?

Let's say there was an `address` column with this data:

`123 Main St@Apt #2@New York NY 10016`

where instead of `@` there was actually a char(10).  We would like it to render in the cell as

```
123 Main St
Apt #2
New York NY 10016
```

There's no design-time preparation in which columns are defined and editors assigned.  This is all ad hoc.

Comment: "Last seen Dec 4 '18"

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Grid](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/grid-grouping-control) supports auto populating data from the underlying data source and the DataSource property can be used to set the data source to the Grid.

[Sample link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DataGrid_Char(10)1498750730)

```
#region DataSource 
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("ID"); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name"); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("Category"); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("SampleData"); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("Description"); 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow(); 
dataRow[0] = i; 
dataRow[1] = "Name" + i.ToString(); 
dataRow[2] = "Category"+i; 
dataRow[3] = "Data" + i.ToString(); 
dataRow[4] = "Decription" + i.ToString(); 
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow); 
} 
//to set the data source for the grid. 
this.gridGroupingControl1.DataSource = dataTable; 
#endregion
```

By default, the char(10) (i.e. the new line char) is addressed as “\r\b”. In order to render the char(10) value in the GridGroupingControl, the CellValue can be modified for display using the QueryCellStyleInfo event.

```
#region Event
//Event triggering 
this.gridGroupingControl1.QueryCellStyleInfo += new GridTableCellStyleInfoEventHandler(gridGroupingControl1_QueryCellStyleInfo);
//Event customization 
void gridGroupingControl1_QueryCellStyleInfo(object sender, GridTableCellStyleInfoEventArgs e) 
{ 
if (e.Style.CellValue != null) 
{ 
    string cellValue = e.Style.CellValue.ToString(); 
    if (cellValue.Contains("char(10")) 
    { 
        cellValue.Replace("char(10)", "\r\b"); 
        e.Style.CellValue = cellValue; 
    } 
} 
} 

#endregion
```

[image: Syncfusion Windows Forms Grid]

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will take a look.